# Nan proplem in JS

Tags: javascript

I have some problem with my js code which when I run the code it show me a `NaN` error, I have a function that calculate something.

Example:

```
<p id = "total "></p>
total = num1 *num2; 
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
```

And it works fine but when I create a new function to calculate the discount

```
var price = document.getElementById("total").value;

discount = total *0.10;
```

It shows a `NaN`, I tried a lot of solution but it is still not working.

Can you help me?

Comment: Hei Noora. Did you try to see what document.getElementById("total").value is? If it's a string that isn't representing a number, that would become NaN when multiplied by a number.

Comment: Additionally, you are not using the value you retrieved (named `price`) in your calculation.

Comment: What you're basically doing is something like `alert(undefined * 0.10)`

Answer (score 0):

When you pull the value, it's a String, and JavaScript for the most part will automatically do type conversion, but you can always wrap it in `parseInt` to force it to be a Number.

```
discount = parseInt(total) * 0.10;
```

You can also always run `typeof total` to verify if `total` is a Number or String, and you can run `console.log(total)` to visually verify the contents.

Also, your `document.getElementById("total")` references a `paragraph` element, which doesn't have `.value` property, so you should use `innerText` to get its value instead.

#### Demo

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  
  
  total = parseInt(num1) * parseInt(num2); 
  document.getElementById("total").innerText = total;
});

button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var total = document.getElementById("total").innerText;
  
  discount = parseInt(total) * 0.10;
  document.getElementById('discount').innerText = discount;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1" /><br>
<input type="text" id="num2" /><br>
<button id="button1">Add</button>
<p id="total"></p>

<button id="button2">Discount</button>
<p id="discount"></p>
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: didn't DV, but it's for a good reason - You see that the `total` element is a paragraph and yet you writing an answer as if it was an input without mentioning  anything that is wrong with the OP's code

Comment: @AlonEitan I did mention what's wrong with OP's code, it's literally the first sentence of my post. Also, nowhere did I make the assumption it was in input.

Comment: Wait a second, can you can the "value" from a  `<p>` element using the `value` property?

Comment: No, I just checked and you can't, so why do you have `var price = document.getElementById("total").value;` in the `button2.addEventListener('click', function() {` callback? You're not using the `price` variable there

Comment: Well perhaps i'm a bit confused by the code, but the description and overall is good enough for me

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code:

1. There is no value property of *p* element. To access the text in *p* element, you can use either *textContent* or *innerText*.
2. By default the text is of type string. Multiplying string with number gives you *NaN*. You have to convert that to number before doing any arithmetic operation.

```js
var num1 = 5;
var num2 = 20;
var total = num1 *num2; 
document.getElementById("total").textContent = total;

var elTotal = Number(document.getElementById("total").textContent);

var discount = elTotal * 0.10;
console.log(discount)
```

```html
<p id = "total"></p>
```

Comment: @Noora.J, If the answer does not solve your problem then your can write it in the comment. If it solves your question then you can accept the answer by *clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in* for the future reader of the post.......thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a concept mistake, if the value is a HTML value, i mean, is inside of

`<p id="this_is_the_element">123456789</p>`

You can get that value with javascript using the

`var number = document.getElementById('this_is_the_element').innerHTML`

now the number variable will have inside "123456789" as a STRING

But if you are using an input you should use

`var number = document.getElementById('this_is_the_element').value`

Now, try this. First try to avoid the parseInt, instead use Number.

Define a function

```
var discount = function(){
   var price = Number(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML);
   return price*0.1;
}
```

If you want to do it on new sintax use this

```
const discount = () => {
   const price = Number(document.getElementById("total").value);
   return price*0.1;
}
```